# How to disable the history in a CDHTMLDialog alternatively prevent from beeing used?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Is there a flag to prevent the CDHTMLDialog from use the IE history (back, backspace, context menu)? Or is there a event to look for?
I don't seem to track it in PreTranslateMessage().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these MSDN references and the sample code:
[TranslateAccelerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7b9bsk6.aspx) and
[ShowContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb367x73.aspx)

```
STDMETHODIMP CDHtmlDialogSubclass::ShowContextMenu(DWORD dwID, POINT *ppt, IUnknown *pcmdtReserved, IDispatch *pdispReserved)
{
    return S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP CDHtmlDialogSubclass::TranslateAccelerator(LPMSG lpMsg, const GUID * pguidCmdGroup, DWORD nCmdID)
{
    if (lpMsg && lpMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN && 
        (lpMsg->wParam == VK_F5 ||
        lpMsg->wParam == VK_CONTROL))
    {
        return S_OK;
    }
    return CDHtmlDialog::TranslateAccelerator(lpMsg, pguidCmdGroup, nCmdID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the fist function was the clue I missed. In the TranslateAccelerator I checked for VK_BACK and it works just fine.

Comment: `//prevent some IE shortcuts
 if( ( GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000 ) 
  && (('N' == pMsg->wParam)      
  || ('O' == pMsg->wParam)    
             || ('L' == pMsg->wParam)     
  || ('P' == pMsg->wParam)))   
  return TRUE; `  
for more control